# Volume is already attached by pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-rook

I install kubernetes on ubuntu on baremetal. I deploy 1 master and 3 worker.
and then deploy rook and every thing work fine.but when i want to deploy a wordpress on it ,it stuck in container creating and then i delete wordpress and now i got this error

> Volume is already attached by pod
>   default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-gvr58. Status Running

```
#kubectl describe pods wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c

Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    3m21s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c to worker2
  Warning  FailedMount  2m57s (x6 over 3m16s)  kubelet, worker2   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-dcba7817-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c" : mount command failed, status: Failure, reason: Rook: Mount volume failed: failed to attach volume pvc-dcba7817-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c for pod default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c. Volume is already attached by pod default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-gvr58. Status Running
  Normal   Pulling      2m26s                  kubelet, worker2   Pulling image "mysql:5.6"
  Normal   Pulled       110s                   kubelet, worker2   Successfully pulled image "mysql:5.6"
  Normal   Created      106s                   kubelet, worker2   Created container mysql
  Normal   Started      101s                   kubelet, worker2   Started container mysql

   for more information
# kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                    STORAGECLASS      REASON   AGE
pvc-dcba7817-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c   20Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/mysql-pv-claim   rook-ceph-block            13m
pvc-e9797517-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c   20Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/wp-pv-claim      rook-ceph-block            13m
#kubectl get pvc
NAME             STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
mysql-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-dcba7817-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c   20Gi       RWO            rook-ceph-block   15m
wp-pv-claim      Bound    pvc-e9797517-553b-11e9-a229-52540076d16c   20Gi       RWO            rook-ceph-block   14m

#kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE          NAME                                  READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
default            wordpress-595685cc49-sdbfk            1/1     Running     6          9m58s
default            wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c       1/1     Running     0          8m14s
kube-system        coredns-fb8b8dccf-plnt4               1/1     Running     0          46m
kube-system        coredns-fb8b8dccf-xrkql               1/1     Running     0          47m
kube-system        etcd-master                           1/1     Running     0          46m
kube-system        kube-apiserver-master                 1/1     Running     0          46m
kube-system        kube-controller-manager-master        1/1     Running     1          46m
kube-system        kube-flannel-ds-amd64-45bsf           1/1     Running     0          40m
kube-system        kube-flannel-ds-amd64-5nxfz           1/1     Running     0          40m
kube-system        kube-flannel-ds-amd64-pnln9           1/1     Running     0          40m
kube-system        kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sg4pv           1/1     Running     0          40m
kube-system        kube-proxy-2xsrn                      1/1     Running     0          47m
kube-system        kube-proxy-mll8b                      1/1     Running     0          42m
kube-system        kube-proxy-mv5dw                      1/1     Running     0          42m
kube-system        kube-proxy-v2jww                      1/1     Running     0          42m
kube-system        kube-scheduler-master                 1/1     Running     0          46m
rook-ceph-system   rook-ceph-agent-8pbtv                 1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph-system   rook-ceph-agent-hsn27                 1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph-system   rook-ceph-agent-qjqqx                 1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph-system   rook-ceph-operator-d97564799-9szvr    1/1     Running     0          27m
rook-ceph-system   rook-discover-26g84                   1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph-system   rook-discover-hf7lc                   1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph-system   rook-discover-jc72g                   1/1     Running     0          26m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-mgr-a-68cb58b456-9rrj7      1/1     Running     0          21m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-mon-a-6469b4c68f-cq6mj      1/1     Running     0          23m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-mon-b-d59cfd758-2d2zt       1/1     Running     0          22m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-mon-c-79664b789-wl4t4       1/1     Running     0          21m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-0-8778dbbc-d84mh        1/1     Running     0          19m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-1-84974b86f6-z5c6c      1/1     Running     0          19m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-2-84f9b78587-czx6d      1/1     Running     0          19m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-prepare-worker1-x4rqc   0/2     Completed   0          20m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-prepare-worker2-29jpg   0/2     Completed   0          20m
rook-ceph          rook-ceph-osd-prepare-worker3-rkp52   0/2     Completed   0          20m
```

Comment: volume is attached to wordpress-mysql deploy

Comment: how can i detach it?

Comment: the volume mode is rwo means it can be attached to only one pod

Comment: what should i do to solve it?

Comment: howmany replicas of mysql are there?

Comment: i have one replica

Comment: Here I can see *two* pods default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c and default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-gvr58

Comment: i use this https://github.com/rook/rook/tree/release-0.9/cluster/examples/kubernetes

Comment: can you run `kubectl get pods,rs,pvc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191089/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-yasin-lachini).

Answer (score 6):

You are using a standard class storage for your PVC, and your policy will be `ReadWriteOnce`. This does not mean you can only connect your PVC to one pod, but only to one *node*.

> `ReadWriteOnce` – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
>
> `ReadWriteMany` – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

Here, seems like you have 2 pods trying to mount this volume. This will be flakey unless you do one of two things:

- [Schedule both pods on the same node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/)
- Use other `storageClasses` such as [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) (FileSystem) to change policy to `ReadWriteMany`
- Downscale to 1 pod, so you don't have to share the volume

Right now you have 2 pods trying to mount the same volume, `default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-gvr58` and `default/wordpress-mysql-b78774f44-bjc2c`.

You can also downscale to 1 pod, so you don't have to worry about any of the above altogether:

```
kubectl scale deploy wordpress-mysql --replicas=1
```

Comment: i hvae one replica now

Comment: can i rook as NFS?

Comment: if i want 3 worker as storage and 5 worker to run pod and create pod in 5 worker and want to attach storage from 3 storag(install rook on them) i should NFS. am i right?

Comment: That seems to be the best way to go, yes!

Comment: do you use rook?