# What node field means in k8s volume.attachments?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I have the following `Volume`:

```yaml
Name:         pvc-c8a0c1ee-b9e6-11e9-9ffa-0cc47ab04738
Namespace:    rook-ceph-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  rook.io/v1alpha2
Attachments:
  Cluster Name:   rook-ceph
  Mount Dir:      /var/lib/kubelet/pods/72fd4f89-5110-49b7-8d88-87488b58695c/volumes/ceph.rook.io~rook-ceph-system/pvc-c8a0c1ee-b9e6-11e9-9ffa-0cc47ab04738
  Node:           node-6.xyz.com
  Pod Name:       dev-cockroachdb-0
  Pod Namespace:  x-namespace
  Read Only:      false
Kind:             Volume
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-08-12T17:13:51Z
  Generation:          6
  Resource Version:    638003207
  Self Link:           /apis/rook.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/rook-ceph-system/volumes/pvc-c8a0c1ee-b9e6-11e9-9ffa-0cc47ab04738
  UID:                 db0a9491-95fe-49cd-8160-89031847d636
Events:                <none>
```

For the pod `dev-cockroachdb-0` I'm getting the following error:

```sh
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-c8a0c1ee-b9e6-11e9-9ffa-0cc47ab04738" : mount command failed, status: Failure, reason: Rook: Mount volume failed: failed to attach volume pvc-c8a0c1ee-b9e6-11e9-9ffa-0cc47ab04738 for pod x-namespace/dev-cockroachdb-0. Volume is already attached by pod x-namespace/dev-cockroachdb-0. Status Pending
```

And the pod `x-namespace/dev-cockroachdb-0` is currently scheduled to `node-5.xyz.com`.

So, as you can see the pod itself is in a different node than the `VolumeAttachment`. `node-6.xyz.com` vs `node-5.xyz.com`.

Questions:

- Does `Node` in `Volume.Attachments` point to the node on which the pod (to which the volume is attached) is located? (So if the volume is attached to a pod on node `NodeA`, then the value of node field for the volume attachment will be `NodeA`)
- May this error happen because of the failure to correctly detach the volume on some node?

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong `access mode` for your volume. Check if this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474193/volume-is-already-attached-by-pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention it but it looks like you have a Rook volume. Perhaps a pvc-clone, something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: rbd-pvc-clone
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
  dataSource:
    name: rbd-pvc
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

> Does Node in Volume.Attachments point to the node on which the pod (to which the volume is attached) is located? (So if the volume is attached to a pod on node NodeA, then the value of node field for the volume attachment will be NodeA)

Not really, your Pod may be trying to start on `node-5.xyz.com`, but the volume could be attached to another node in your case it's `node-6.xyz.com`.

> May this error happen because of the failure to correctly detach the volume on some node?

Yes, this error may happen if maybe you had another pod running in `node-6.xyz.com` that terminated and failed to detach.

Keep in mind that all of the above is considering that your volume has `accessModes: ReadWriteOnce`. It looks like you are using Ceph with Rook and in that case, you can also use [`accessModes: ReadWriteMany`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) which would essentially allow you to attach the volume to Kubernetes nodes.

✌️